# Hibernate one-to-one .. Do not persist dependent object if its table is empty

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, one-to-one

Am using hibernate with `one-to-one` mapping.

I have 2 tables `Customer` and `CustomerAddress`.

`CstId` is the primary key in Customer table and it is the foreign key in CustomerAddress table. I have a sql which does left outer join on both table to fetch different column values from both tables.

**Problem:** For first time, `CustomerAddress` table is empty, after doing some updates on the `Customer` object table am saving the `Customer` object. This is creating a row of `CustomerAddress` to be created with same `CstId`,

**Required Solution:** I dont want `CustomerAddress` row to be persisted unless there exists a row in `CustomerAddress` for the `CstId` from `Customer`.

**Mappings:**
*Customer.hbm.xml*
    `<one-to-one name="customerAddress" class="com.test.CustomerAddress" fetch="join" lazy="false" cascade="save-update, merge"/>`

*CustomerAdress.hbm.xml*
    `<one-to-one name="Customer" class="com.test.Customer" constrained="true" />`

Comment: If the table is empty at first, and you don't want to persist data there, when will the table be non-empty?

Comment: that table will be updated by some other process, but if the table is empty or doesnt have a correspoding `CustId`, saving `Customer` should not persist `customerAdress`

Comment: Then don't cascade anything else but updates.

Comment: can you please give an example for just updating..

Comment: I could, but it's better for you to find it out by yourself. Not too hard to Google for Hibernate's cascade types.

Comment: I don't see any cascade option just for update rather than save-update. Can you please suggest.

Comment: You're right, Hibernate doesn't seem to have a (even native) cascade option for updates only. I recommend letting `CustomerAddress` be persisted with `Customer` and having the other processes then modify the already persisted entities.

Comment: am not able to get proper solution for this, can you please help me on this.